# Hiding scrollbars (still able to scroll) not working when content width is auto

Tags: html, css, width, scrollbar, overflow

The [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/2272048) to the problem of visible scrollbars does not work in the below scenario :

**[JSFIDDLe](http://jsfiddle.net/50fam5g9/7/)**

CSS:

```
#hider {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hider">
    <div id="scroller">
        <div id="content">
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the `width` of `<div id="content"></div>` cannot be known beforehand in my case, that's why I need to set it to `auto`.

In that case, the scrollbars are still hidden and the scrolling still works but there is one small "glitch" :

If you scroll all the way to the right, you'll notice that the last bit of `<div id="content"></div>` is cut off.

More specifically, the width of the part of `<div id="content"></div>` that is hidden on the right is equal to the width of the right padding applied to `<div id="scroller"></div>`. This is very weird.

Why is that and how do I work around that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving `padding-right` to `#content` class seems to solve the problem.

```
#content {
    padding-right: 10px; /* increase or decrease */
    /* other styles */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/50fam5g9/12/)**

Comment: Actually, a padding-right of around 30px seems to do the trick so that's great Mr_Green thanks a lot! :-)